# Laragon :How to import large mysql dump

Tags: mysql, laragon

I have a Laragon set up and have a 17G mysql dump to be imported to mysql. Since phpMyAdmin doesn't support such large file imports, is there a way to import such a large dump?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally found it...

`cmd>cd <laragon_path>\bin`

`<laragon_path>\bin>mysql -u <user> -p <dbname> < <filename_with_path>;`

Comment: To upgrade this answer: use the cmd from laragon

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something slightly different.

```
cmd>cd <laragon_path>\bin
```

```
<laragon_path>\bin>mysql -u <user> -D <dbname> < <filename_with_path>;
```